# Is it possible to edit name in a paper at the stage of pre-proof correction after acceptance?

Tags: journals, authorship, editors, proofreading

I am a part of a collaboration in an article. The paper is accepted in a journal and we are asked to check the pre-proof version. Now I see initial part of my name is missing. For, example if my name is "St. Stephen Bas", in that case, "St." is missing. I didn't submit the paper, my corresponding author submitted.

Can we edit the name before sending the pre-proof to journal?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, editing mis-spellings and other obvious mistakes is possible at this stage. Contact the editor, journal staff, or the person with whom you have communicated about the proofs as soon as you can, and ask to have that change made.

Comment: @FerventHippo Yes, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the problem is just the misspelling of your full name, you can edit it. If the problem is to add an extra author, then it's *usually* not possible.

See comments for details

Comment: "If the problem is to add an extra author, then it's not possible." I would not be so absolute about this. You might have some explaining to do, and sometimes it might really be impossible. However, if there is a good reason to add an author, quite some journals/editors will accept.

Comment: At the stage of pre-proof? I don't think so. Maybe in predatory journals.

Comment: It's definitely possible. It's unethical to leave out an author. If a legitimate author is missed, misspelled, or mis-affiliated, then a separate correction has to be published. It's far better to have the author added before publication than to fix it otherwise.

Comment: You can even add an author after publication. Journals have a process in place for it.

Comment: It's very rare and confined to cases where the authorship is disputed. It's absolutely not the norm and it shouldn't be. This practice is seen with suspicion since it's used to sell authorship of papers that have already been accepted. If you look in the Retraction watch blog you can read some articles about this. Of course I clarified in my comment that corrections of authors' names are possible.